# How to get interest earned from start of repayment to a specific date on a declining balance?

Tags: loans, interest, compound-interest

I need a formula in getting the interest earned from start of payment of my loan to a specific date. I know the formula for the current due interest, which my company have given me in excel:

```
days = DateDiff(LastPaymentDate, CurrentPaymentDate, "D")
Due Interest = Principal Remaining * Int. Rate * days / 360
```

but these formula only gives me my current due interest. I would like to get my interest from the start to a specific point in time as if I have not paid any interest from it. I have googled for formulas but only found formulas on monthly or the whole life of the loan. By the way this is the details of my loan:

```
Principal        = 70000
Annual Interest  = 8%
Terms            = 3 years
Payment Freq.    = Monthly
```

Sample scenario

```
Payment Start    = Jan - 2016
Payment Date     = March 15 2016
Interes Earned (Jan 01 to March 15) = ?
```

Answer (score 1):

The formula you require is

`interest = (d+d q-r s-(1+q) (1+r)^x (d-r s)+d r x)/r`

where

```
d is the monthly payment
r is the monthly rate = 0.08/12
s is the principal = 70000
x is the number of complete months = 2
q is the interest factor for the incomplete month = Int. Rate * days / 360
```

Obtaining the monthly payment amount `d` using the [loan payment formula](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html)

`d = r s/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)` where `n = 36 months`

```
∴ d = 70000 r/(1 - (1 + r)^-36) = 2193.55
```

Taking the OP's specification for interest due

```
q = Int. Rate * days / 360 = 0.08 * 15/360
```

and applying the formula

```
interest = (d + d q - r s - (1 + q) (1 + r)^x (d - r s) + d r x)/r = 1143.6
```

The interest accrued from January to March 15th is 1143.6

To explain and demonstrate the method, first obtain the interest for just the first two months

```
x = 2
q = 0
interest = (d + d q - r s - (1 + q) (1 + r)^x (d - r s) + d r x)/r = 921.821
```

Check: the first two months interest = `70000 r + (70000 (1 + r) - d) r = 921.821`

The balance after two months = `(70000 (1 + r) - d) (1 + r) - d = 66534.7`

15 days interest on the balance = `66534.7 * 0.08 * 15/360 = 221.782`

`interest = 921.821 + 221.782 = 1143.6` which matches the formula's result.

Another example: interest paid after 20 months and 10 days.

```
x = 20
q = 0.08 * 10/360
interest = (d + d q - r s - (1 + q) (1 + r)^x (d - r s) + d r x)/r = 7129.67
```

**Derivation of the formula**

Here is the calculation in longhand leading to the resulting formula.

*r* is the monthly rate, *s* is the principal, *n* is the number of months and *d* is the monthly payment

```
r = 0.08/12
s = 70000
n = 36

d = (r (1+r)^n s)/(-1+(1+r)^n) = 2193.55
```

Calculating interest for each month and the end-of-month balance.

```
int[jan2016] = 70000 r
```

> 466.667

```
end[jan2016] = 70000 (1 + r) - d
```

> 68273.1

```
int[feb2016] = end[jan2016] r
```

> 455.154

```
end[feb2016] = end[jan2016] (1 + r) - d
```

> 66534.7

Calculating the interest for 15 days on the balance.  One may use an approximate method such as `Int. Rate * days / 360`.  Here instead I have taken the daily rate as the 365th root of the [annual effective rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation): `(1 + Int. Rate/12)^(days 12/365) - 1`) which is how I would usually obtain a daily rate.

```
int[mar15th2016] = end[feb2016] ((1 + r)^(15*12/365) - 1)
```

> 218.376

Interest from Jan to March 15th `= 466.667 + 455.154 + 218.376 = 1140.2`

**Solving the recurrence equation**

The solution for `end[x + 1] = end[x] (1 + r) - d` where `end[0] = s` is

```
pn = (d-d (1+r)^x+r (1+r)^x s)/r
```

[image]

This can be used to find the balance after any `x` number of complete months.

```
with x = 1
p1 = pn = 68273.1
int1 = p1 + d - s = 466.667

with x = 2
p2 = pn = 66534.7
int2 = p2 + d - p1 = 455.154

int3 = p2 ((1 + r)^(15*12/365) - 1) = 218.376
```

Interest from Jan to March 15th `= int1 + int2 + int3 = 1140.2`

**Extending the formula**

The recurrence solution can be used in a summation for the interest after `x` complete months.

[image]

The closed-form for the summation can be found by induction

```
bx = (d (1+x r-(1+r)^x)+r (-1+(1+r)^x) s)/r
```

[image]

```
with x = 2
b2 = bx = 921.821

total = b2 + p2 ((1 + r)^(15*12/365) - 1) = 1140.2
```

**Final formula**

Putting the formulas `bx` & `pn` together and simplifying, with `q` as the interest factor for the odd 15 days.

```
q = (1 + r)^(15*12/365) - 1

x = 2

bx = (d (1 + x r - (1 + r)^x) + r (-1 + (1 + r)^x) s)/r
pn = (d - d (1 + r)^x + r (1 + r)^x s)/r

total = bx + pn q = (d (1 + x r - (1 + r)^x) + r (-1 + (1 + r)^x) s)/r +
                    q (d - d (1 + r)^x + r (1 + r)^x s)/r

∴ total = (d+d q-r s-(1+q) (1+r)^x (d-r s)+d r x)/r = 1140.2
```

And alternatively, with the OP's method for calculating the daily accrual.

```
q = 0.08 * 15/360

total = (d+d q-r s-(1+q) (1+r)^x (d-r s)+d r x)/r = 1143.6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know:

```
- S:  the original balance of the loan at the start. 70000)
- C:  the current balance of the loan. (69000)
- P:  the total amount of payments made. (3000)
```

To know how much in interest:

```
I = P- (S - C) = 3000 - (70000 - 69000) = 3000 - 1000 = 2000
```